# In how many ways can n men and n women sit in n seats serially, so that no 3 women sit consecutively

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I tried a lot, but couldn't find a way.

One thing which I found interesting is that

for n = 7, the maximum women can be 
W W M W W M W = 5.
Hope this might help someone to give an answer.

Comment: You say, $n$ men and $n$ women sit in $n$ seats... there are too many people to all sit down, are you saying that only some of the people will sit and others wont?  Are your people considered distinct, or are they indistinguishable apart from gender?

Comment: Yes according to question M M M M M M M is also a combination

Comment: all men are same and all women are same

Comment: See the linked question.  Replace the flavor from being $1$'s and $0$'s, to being Men and Women respectively.

Comment: Do you mean $m$ men and $w$ women in $n=m+w$ seats? You should be able to set up a set of recurrences and possibly give a generating function

Comment: @Henry no N men N women and N seats, some people will stay standing